# I am getting a "System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception_WasThrown'" at InitializeComponent() , and I cant for the life of me figure out why

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, p2p

I'm trying to make a p2p chat application in c# with WPF and MVVM but I keep getting the error in the title at InitializeComponent(). I am providing all my files down below, please take a look.

MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace P2PChat
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel _viewModel;
        //private bool taskStarted = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            _viewModel.Contacts = new List<Contact>();
            _viewModel.Username = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter your username:", "P2P Chat", "User");
            _viewModel.Port = Int32.Parse(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter the Port you want to listen from:", "P2P Chat", "8080"));
            this.Title = _viewModel.Username + " - " + GetLocalIPAddress();
            _viewModel.SelectedContact = new Contact("", "", 0);
            MessageBox.Show(GetLocalIPAddress());
            Task.Factory.StartNew(ListenForMessages);

        }
        // Event handler for when the user clicks the "Send" button
        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = MessageTextBox.Text;
            MessageTextBox.Text = "";
            ChatListBox.Items.Add(_viewModel.Username + ": " + message);
            _viewModel.SendMessage(message);
        }

        // Event handler for when the user clicks the "Add Contact" button
        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string username = UsernameTextBox.Text;
            string ipAddress = IpAddressTextBox.Text;
            int contactPort = Int32.Parse(PortTextBox.Text);
            _viewModel.AddContact(username, ipAddress, contactPort, _viewModel.Port);
        }

        // Event handler for when the user clicks the "Remove" button
        private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object selectedItem = ContactListBox.SelectedItem;
            if (selectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a contact to remove.", "Error");
                return;
            }

            string contact = (string)ContactListBox.SelectedItem;
            _viewModel.SelectedContact = _viewModel.Contacts.Find(c => c.Username == contact);
            _viewModel.RemoveContact();

            ContactListBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Contact c in _viewModel.Contacts)
            {
                ContactListBox.Items.Add(c.ToString());
            }
        }

        // Event handler for when the user double-clicks a contact in the list
        private void ContactListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_viewModel.Contacts != null)
            {
                string selectedUsername = (string)ContactListBox.SelectedItem;
                _viewModel.SelectedContact = _viewModel.Contacts.Find(c => c.Username == selectedUsername);

                ChatListBox.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string message in _viewModel.SelectedContact.Messages)
                {
                    ChatListBox.Items.Add(_viewModel.SelectedContact.Username + ": " + message);
                }
            }
        }


        public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
        }

      
        private void ListenForMessages()
        {
            if (_viewModel.taskStarted)
            {
                // Task has already been started, so do nothing
                return;
            }

            // Set the taskStarted flag to true
            _viewModel.taskStarted = true;

            // Create a socket to listen for incoming messages
            var listener = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the localhost IP address and port 8080
            listener.Bind(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPAddress()), _viewModel.Port));
            listener.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {
                var client = listener.Accept();
                var data = new byte[1024];
                int bytesReceived = client.Receive(data);
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesReceived);

                // Check if the message is a contact message
                if (message.StartsWith("CONTACT:"))
                {
                    // Extract the contact information from the message
                    string[] parts = message.Split(':');
                    string username = parts[1];
                    string ipAddress = parts[2];
                    int Contactport = Int32.Parse(parts[3]);

                    // Display a message box or some other UI element to allow the user to accept or reject the request
                    MessageBoxResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add " + username + " as a contact?", "Add Contact", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);


                    if (MessageBoxResult.Yes == answer)
                    {

                        _viewModel.SendConfirmation(ipAddress, Contactport, _viewModel.Port, true);

                        // Add the contact to the list
                        Contact contact = new Contact(username, ipAddress, Contactport);
                        _viewModel.Contacts.Add(contact);
                        ContactListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            ContactListBox.Items.Clear();
                            foreach (Contact c in _viewModel.Contacts)
                            {
                                ContactListBox.Items.Add(c.ToString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _viewModel.SendConfirmation(ipAddress, Contactport, _viewModel.Port, false);
                    }
                }
                else if (message.StartsWith("RESPONSE:"))
                {

                    string[] parts = message.Split(':');
                    string response = parts[1];
                    string username = parts[2];
                    string ipAddress = parts[3];
                    int Contactport = Int32.Parse(parts[4]);
                    if (response == "True")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The user " + username + " accepted your friend request");
                        Contact contact = new Contact(username, ipAddress, Contactport);
                        _viewModel.Contacts.Add(contact);
                        ContactListBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            ContactListBox.Items.Clear();
                            foreach (Contact c in _viewModel.Contacts)
                            {
                                ContactListBox.Items.Add(c.ToString());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if (response == "False")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The user " + username + " rejected your friend request");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Contact c in _viewModel.Contacts)
                    {
                        if (c.ToString() == _viewModel.SelectedContact.Username)
                        {
                            // Handle regular messages here
                            SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
                            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ChatListBox.Items.Add(_viewModel.SelectedContact.Username + ": " + message));
                            client.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        



    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs file:

```
// ViewModel class
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace P2PChat
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        //public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        // Properties
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public Contact SelectedContact { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string ip { get; set; }

        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool Response { get; set; }

        public bool taskStarted = false;

        // Constructor
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Contacts = new List<Contact>();
            SelectedContact = new Contact("", "", 0);
            ip = Contact.GetLocalIPAddress();
            //Task.Factory.StartNew(MainWindow.ListenForMessages());
}

        // Methods
        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            SelectedContact.SendMessage(message, SelectedContact.IpAddress, SelectedContact.Contactport);
        }

        public void AddContact(string username, string ipAddress, int contactPort, int port)
        {
            SelectedContact.SendContactInfo(username, ipAddress, contactPort, port);
        }

        public void RemoveContact()
        {
            Contacts.Remove(SelectedContact);
        }

        public void SendConfirmation(string Contactip, int Contactport, int port, bool answer)
        {
            string message;
            if (answer)
            {
                message = "RESPONSE:True" + ":" + Username + ":" + ip + ":" + port.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                message = "RESPONSE:False" + ":" + Username + ":" + ip + ":" + port.ToString();
            }
            var socket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(Contactip, Contactport);
            socket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message));
            socket.Close();
        }

        
        
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="P2PChat.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:P2PChat"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:P2PChat"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="P2P Chat" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindow x:Key="Locator"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <ListBox x:Name="ContactListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Username"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}"
                 MouseDoubleClick="ContactListBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="ChatListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="375" Margin="230,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="550"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedContact.Messages}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Username"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="MessageTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="77" Margin="230,405,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450"
                 Text="{Binding MessageText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button x:Name="SendButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="694,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
                Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding MessageText}"
                Height="66"
                Content="Send"
                Click="SendButton_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="AddButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,523,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                Command="{Binding AddContactCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Port}"
                Content="Add Contact"/>
        <Button x:Name="RemoveButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,548,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                Command="{Binding RemoveContactCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedContact}"
                Content="Remove Contact"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="UsernameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="47,425,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                 Text="{Binding ContactUsername, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="IpAddressTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="47,453,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                 Text="{Binding ContactIpAddress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PortTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="47,481,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
                 Text="{Binding ContactPort, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Label Content="Port:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,480,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="IP:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,456,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Username:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-19,425,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It worked fine when I didnt use MVVM but apparently its a requirement for this assignment and I am really stumped.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  In the constructor, add handler for the `Loaded` event.  Take all of that code in the constructor that comes after you set the DataContext property and move it to this handler.  I'm not saying it will solve your problem, but it's better to do that sort of work after the view is loaded...

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in the XAML. A name maybe. Can you reduce the components in the XAML and post the minimal reproducible code?